# How to restrict unsigned users from viewing certain static pages - Rails4

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

i am new to rails and your help would be much appreciated.

1. i want an unsigned user to be able to view only the static page `landingpg` but not the `homepg` & `aboutpg`
2. the static pages homepg & aboutpg can be viewed by unsigned users but for now i would like to restrict the unsigned users from viewing the homepg & aboutpg

> could one advise me the best way to go about this?

```
class StaticPagesController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :html, :xml, :json

  def aboutpg
    @timelines = Timeline.order("created_at DESC")
  end

  def homepg
    @reviews = Review.limit(3).all
    @search = Advert.search(params[:q])
    @adverts = @search.result(distinct: true)
    @companies = Company.all
  end

  def landingpg 
    @signup = Signup.new
  end
end
```

route.rb

```
  root    'static_pages#landingpg'
  get     'about',                  to: 'static_pages#aboutpg'
  get     'home',                   to: 'static_pages#homepg'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include a `before_filter` or `before_action` that will run a method before your action is called.  If the method redirects to another path, then the call to the action is bypassed.

```
class StaticPagesController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :html, :xml, :json

  before_filter :user_allowed, only: [:aboutpg, :homepg]

  def aboutpg
    @timelines = Timeline.order("created_at DESC")
  end

  def homepg
    @reviews = Review.limit(3).all
    @search = Advert.search(params[:q])
    @adverts = @search.result(distinct: true)
    @companies = Company.all
  end

  def landingpg 
    @signup = Signup.new
  end

  def user_allowed
    unless current_user
      flash[:error] = "Please sign in first."
      redirect_to root_path
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

hi you need to add before_filter.

```
  Class StaticPagesControlle  < ApplicationController
    before_filter :not_allowed ,:only => [:homepg,:aboutpg]
      #rest is your code
   end
       #and in application controller or your StaticPageController do this
       class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
         #define that method
         def not_allowed
           if current_user is unsigned (# here your logic for a user to be unsigend)
             render json: {
             status: 401,    
             message: 'You are not an authorised person to access this page'
            }
          end
          end
```